# PopoverPresentationController coming as nil

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

Created a SingleViewApplication in that I have placed a button.

Now clicking on button I need to display a tableView as popover.
The TableViewController is created in xib.

The issue is tableViewController.popoverPresentationController always comes as nil see below code

```
     let filterVC =  TableViewController(nibName: "TableViewController", bundle: nil)
    var filterDistanceViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: filterVC)
    filterDistanceViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 200)
    let popoverPresentationViewController = filterDistanceViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any


    if let pop = filterDistanceViewController.popoverPresentationController {
        pop.delegate = self
    }
```

in above code
filterDistanceViewController.popoverPresentationController is always coming as nil

Any hint in right direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you set your VC as root on the Interface Builder? by checking on the box that makes an arrow appear indicating which one is your root view controller.

Comment: The ViewCtr from which the button is placed is the rootviewCtr. Do i need to make TableVC as the rootVC ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not presenting anything, so you need to present the `popoverPresentationViewController` on the current viewcontroller, for example:

```
@IBAction func importantButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
         let tableViewController = UITableViewController()
         tableViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

         present(tableViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        if let pop = tableViewController.popoverPresentationController {
          pop.delegate = self
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 13):

Until you've set a `modalPresentationStyle` on your VC, the `popoverPresentationController` property will be `nil`. Ensure that you set the `modalPresentationStyle` before accessing.

Comment: and the style must be `Popover`

Comment: `.popover` you mean?

Comment: oh yes, I'm using xamarin now, so I have been used to the capital form.

Comment: BRILLIANT! I love how crappy apple designs their APIs.

Answer (score 3):

You may do like below.

```
@IBAction func popoverBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let vc2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2")
    vc2.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    vc2.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    vc2.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = popoverBtn
    vc2.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = .zero
    present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```