# Drop down list ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, popover

I want to have a small UItableView that popup when  clicked and shows some numbers in  the list.

I tried to use popoverPresentationController but it appears full screen for iOS(iPhone) devices.

below is the code for same -

```
let filterVC =  TableViewController(nibName: "TableViewController", bundle: nil)
              filterVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 200)

    filterVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover

    present(filterVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    let popoverPresentationController = filterVC.popoverPresentationController

    if let pop = filterVC.popoverPresentationController {
        pop.delegate = self
    }

       popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView
    popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame
```

//-------

with below method also

```
  func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    // Return no adaptive presentation style, use default presentation behaviour
    return .none
}
```

//-----
Any hint in right direction would be highly appreciated.
working  sample would be greatly helpful

What I am trying to achieve as below

[image: dropdwon 1]

[image: dropdown 2]

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

There is a useful [library](https://github.com/linhcn/LCUIComponents) you may want to give a try.

---

It's because your `pop.delegate` was assigned after you present the `filterVC`.

Move this

```
if let pop = filterVC.popoverPresentationController {
    pop.delegate = self
    pop.sourceView = sender
    pop.sourceRect = sender.bounds
}
present(filterVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to the init of your `filterVC` should do the trick. Btw, I didn't see anywhere you have assigned `sourceView` and `sourceRect` for your `popoverPresentationController`. Moving `pop.delegate = self` to this part should be appropriate. Something like

```
init(for sender: UIView)) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    guard let pop = popoverPresentationController else { return }
    pop.sourceView = sender
    pop.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    pop.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: I had tried to do that but resulted into nil problem refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666281/popoverpresentationcontroller-coming-as-nil/44668202#44668202

Comment: I mean you move `present(filterVC, animated: true, completion: nil)` to after set `pop.delegate`. Have you tried this? You can check my edited answer.