# Popover on iPhone (Swift 3) from Programmatically Created Button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I am trying to have a popover appear on an iPhone when I click on a programmatically created button. However, I am instead finding that the popover is taking over the entire screen. I've coded the following thus far in the popover view controller's class:

```
import UIKit

class GroupSetsPopoverController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 375, height: 162)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "infoButtonSegue" {
        let popoverViewController = segue.destination as! GroupSetsPopoverController

        let pvc = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController
        pvc?.delegate = self

        //popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        //popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. I've tried to follow various tutorials and posts here on Stack Overflow, to no avail.

Comment: Is `GroupSetsPopoverController` the `popover` `viewController` or the `controller` trying to present a `popover` `viewController`?

Comment: By saying "taking over the entire screen", you mean the popover displays as normal, but the background view is blurry, or the popover didn't display correctly and the background view is black?

Comment: Harry Singh, GroupSetsPopoverControllee is the popover viewcontroller.

Comment: Lawliet, the popover seems to show as a normal view controller, with the text I want to display on top and the rest of the view white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688987/7113238) and [library](https://github.com/linhcn/LCUIComponents) for your references. If the GroupSetsPopoverController is your popover viewcontroller, you can do something like this:

```
init(for sender: UIView)) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    guard let pop = popoverPresentationController else { return }
    pop.sourceView = sender
    pop.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    pop.delegate = self
}
```